# Broadcom BCM4352 Wireless not working with 16.10

Tags: networking, drivers, broadcom, 16.10, xps

I believe I've tried all proposed solutions for other questions involving the Broadcom BCM4352 wifi hardware, but on a fresh install of Ubuntu 16.10  on a Dell XPS 13 9343 (2015) I cannot get the system to recognise the device.

Output of `sudo lshw -C network`:

```
  *-network
       description: Network controller
       product: BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Broadcom Limited
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: 03
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=bcma-pci-bridge latency=0
       resources: irq:19 memory:f7200000-f7207fff memory:f7000000-f71fffff
```

Output of `rfkill list all` (only bluetooth is recognised, not wifi):

```
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Output of `lspci -knn | grep -A2 Net`:

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Limited BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:43b1] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Dell BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [1028:0019]
    Kernel driver in use: bcma-pci-bridge
    Kernel modules: bcma, wl
```

Secure boot is disabled in the BIOS:

[image]

Wifi hardware is not shown in the Network Manager indicator:

[image]

I have selected `bcmwl-kernel-source` from the additional drivers application:

[image]

The `wl` module is loaded and and I have tried removing and reloading it.

I have also tried unloading `wl`, uninstalling and purging `bcmwl-kernel-source` and installing `firmware-b43-installer` and `b43-fwcutter`, but the problem remains the same.

The wireless hardware works in Windows 10 and older versions of Ubuntu up until 16.04 so there is no question of a hardware fault.

What else can I try to get the device working or debug the problem?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: I see that `wl` is installed, but not loaded. Please post the output of `sudo modprobe wl` command.

Comment: @Pilot6, `wl` does appear to be loaded in `lsmod`. I've just tried removing and reloading it (neither generates output) but no effect.

Comment: Try `sudo modprobe -r bcma && sudo modprobe wl`

Comment: I had to run `sudo modprobe -r bcma && sudo modprobe -r wl && sudo modprobe wl` but then it works! I tried blacklisting `bcma` in /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`, but `bcma` still loads and takes priority at startup. Any idea why that might be? By the way, your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: How did you blacklist it?

Comment: I added the line `blacklist bcma` to `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`. Later I discovered the line was already present in `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-bcm43.conf` though neither seems to have any affect. bcma is still loaded. No other modules rely on it, and it's not in `/etc/modules` or `/etc/initramfs-tools/modules`. I can't tell what's loading it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have found that, even though it is properly blacklisted, *bcma* loads anyway!! Let's correct it in rc.local.

Please do:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/systemd/system/rc-local.service
```

Put in the following:

```
[Unit]
 Description=/etc/rc.local Compatibility
 ConditionPathExists=/etc/rc.local

[Service]
 Type=forking
 ExecStart=/etc/rc.local start
 TimeoutSec=0
 StandardOutput=tty
 RemainAfterExit=yes
 SysVStartPriority=99

[Install]
 WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Proofread carefully, save and close the text editor. Next:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/rc.local
```

Place the following:

```
#!/bin/sh -e

modprobe -r wl
modprobe -r bcma
modprobe wl

exit 0
```

Proofread carefully, save and close the text editor. Next:

```
sudo chmod +rx /etc/rc.local

sudo systemctl enable rc-local

sudo systemctl start rc-local.service
sudo systemctl status rc-local.service
```

If there are no errors, reboot and test.

Comment: Are there any items related to wl or bcma or b43 or ssb listed in `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` or in `/etc/modules` ?

Comment: `/etc/modules` is empty. `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` contains the line `blacklist bcm43xx` but nothing else related to wireless as far as I can see.

Comment: Can you confirm that when you reboot,  both bcma and wl load? `lsmod` What is your ethernet device? `lspci -nnk | grep 0200 -A2`

Comment: Yes, both are loaded. `lspci` output is in the question.

Comment: I see the `lspci` for your wireless, but I asked for the ethernet. There is a conflict with some Broadcom ethernet drivers.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47463/discussion-between-chili555-and-ian-mackinnon).