# Dell XPS 13 Not Discovering any Wifi Networks

Tags: networking, drivers, dell, broadcom

So my wifi just died randomly this morning and I haven't been able to get it back would appreciate any help I can get.

I have been following this link with little to no success [Broadcom BCM4352 Wireless not working with 16.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/841971/broadcom-bcm4352-wireless-not-working-with-16-10) here are my results of running the same types of tests

lshw -C network

```
*-network                 
   description: Wireless interface
   product: BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
   vendor: Broadcom Limited
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
   logical name: wlan0
   version: 03
   serial: 6a:cc:51:5a:8b:d9
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=wl0 driverversion=6.30.223.271 (r587334) latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
   resources: irq:19 memory:f7200000-f7207fff memory:f7000000-f71fffff
```

rfkill list all

```
 0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

lspci -knn | grep -A2 Net

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Limited BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:43b1] (rev 03)
Subsystem: Dell BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [1028:0019]
Kernel driver in use: wl
Kernel modules: bcma, wl
```

I have also refollowed the installation guide for wl but haven't had any success yet would appreciate any help I can get.

Comment: Let's check the log by looking at entries for the interface (wlan0) and/or the driver (wl). Please open a terminal and run: `dmesg | grep -e wlan -e wl` Next, edit your question to add the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had foolishly disabled the Wifi with my keyboard and had not noticed it. Funnily enough this was not the same as airplane mode, as airplane mode was not considered on.

Hopefully if nothing else someone who may have done the same will find this answer if they are having an off day as I clearly did today.

Comment: Yes, embarrassingly simple to do. Fn + PrtScn will solve.